# What functions are involved in minix 3's echo

Tags: function, echo, minix

I'd like to understand what actual files and functions are used in minix 3s echo function.The actual function that is called in the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking of the shell builtin `echo` function, you can see how it works by looking at its source code. You can clone the repository from [here](http://git.minix3.org/?p=minix.git) or you can browse it online [here](http://git.minix3.org/?p=minix.git;a=blob;f=commands/ash/bltin/echo.c;h=72bb60e52f029d5035c41215ad9ce5cd0ff129e3;hb=HEAD)